# PHP Regex XML to allow attributes

Tags: php, xml, regex

```
/<peanut\:compressedContent>(.*?)<\/peanut\:compressedContent>/si
```

currently support no attributes but i also want to capture the stuff even if it has attributes.

Comment: ["Have you tried using an XML parser instead?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: this is just extracting compressed gzip content; then gunziping it and then i am using simple xml parser..

Comment: Don't use REGEX when you should use DOM/XML parsing. See: http://php.net/DOM and http://php.net/xml

Comment: I am not using a full XML Document!

Comment: By using your method: because i am not using a full crystal clear xml document its a binary document with alot of hex jibberish and partial xml... long story....

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\gunzip.php on line 19

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\gunzip.php on line 19

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: in C:\xampp\htdocs\gunzip.php on line 19

Comment: so in short would someone just help me with my question... i am aware of simple xml and others.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html#~HTML

You can use `[^>]*` to match/ignore anything within tags. Likewise you might want to use `[^<>]*` instead of `.*?` for ensuring it only matches text content:

```
/<peanut:compressedContent[^>]*>([^<>]*)<\/peanut:compressedContent>/si
```